# Connection closed before finishing the inserts in the database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, async-await

I'm creating my first application in Node.js that should perform these operations in order:

1. connects to a PostgreSQL database
2. create a table (if it already exists, do anything)
3. makes web scraping of two websites and saves information on db
4. create visualizations using D3.js and data on the database
5. it disconnects from database.

I posted a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49538508/insert-operation-using-node-js-and-postgresql-doesnt-work) concerning the insert operation. Now the problem is async/await.

I know that Node.js is asynchronous while I should do the operations synchronously.
I'm using Node.js v8.9.4 so I use the async/await construct.

I read a bit 'how async / await but I find it hard to use it properly.

This is the scheme of my app (**app.js** file):

```
const postgreSQLlib = require('./middlewares/postgreSQLlib.js')
const scraperCovIt = require('./routers/scraperCovIt.js');
const scraperCov = require('./routers/scraperCov.js');

const start = async function() {
    // STEP 0 - Start
    await console.log('\nSTART');

    // STEP 1 - Connect to db
    await postgreSQLlib.connect();

    // STEP 2 - Create tables
    var queryCreateCoverages = {
        text: 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coverages ('+
                    'id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,' +
                    'vaccine VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,' + 
                    'country VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,' +
                    'region VARCHAR(255),' +
                    'year VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,' +
                    'value VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL);'
    };
    var queryRes = await postgreSQLlib.query(queryCreateCoverages, '[CREATE TABLE coverages]');

    // STEP 3 - Get data
    await scraperCovIt.download();
    await scraperCov.download();

    // STEP 4 - Disconnect from db
    await postgreSQLlib.disconnect();

    // STEP 5 - End
    return '\nFINISH';
}

// start application
start()
.then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

**postgreSQLlib.js**:

```
const {Client} = require('pg'); 
const connectionString = 'postgres://admin:admin@localhost:5432/db';
let client;
var methods = {};

methods.connect = async function() {
    client = new Client({connectionString});
    return await client.connect()
    .then(async function() {
        await console.log('\nConnected to ' + client.database + ' at ' + client.host + ':' + client.port + ' as ' + client.user + ' (pass: ' + client.password + ')');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('\nError during connection to PostgreSQL');
        throw err;
    });
}

methods.query = async function(query, print) {
    return await client.query(query)
    .then(function(res) {
        console.log(print, 'OK query');
        return res;
    })
    .catch(function(err) { 
        console.log(print, 'ERR query');
    });
}

methods.disconnect = async function() {
    return await client.end()
    .then(function() {
        console.log('\nConnection has ended');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('\nError during clossing connection');
        throw err;
    }); 
}

module.exports = methods;
```

**scraperCov.js**:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request-promise');
var postgreSQLlib = require('../middlewares/postgreSQLlib.js');

var methods = {};

var countries = {
    'Albania': 'ALB',
    'Austria': 'AUT',
    'Belgium': 'BEL'
};

methods.download = async function(req, res) {
    for(country in countries) {
        console.log('\nCOUNTRY:', country);
        var url = 'http://apps.who.int/immunization_monitoring/globalsummary/coverages?c=' + countries[country];
        let res = await request(url);
        insert(res);
    }
}

module.exports = methods;

let insert = async function(html) {
    $ = cheerio.load(html);

    var years = [];
    var vaccines = [];
    var coverages = [];

    $('.ts .year').each(function() {
        years.push($(this).text().trim());
    });
    $('.ts .odd td a, .ts .even td a').each(function() {
        vaccines.push($(this).text().trim());
    });
    $('.ts .odd .statistics_small, .ts .even .statistics_small').each(function() {
        coverages.push($(this).text().trim());
    });

    const numYears = years.length;
    const numVaccines = vaccines.length;
    for(var vaccineIdx = 0; vaccineIdx < numVaccines; vaccineIdx++) {
        for(var yearIdx = 0; yearIdx < numYears; yearIdx++) {
            let obj = {
                year: years[yearIdx],
                country: country,
                region: '',
                vaccine: vaccines[vaccineIdx],
                coverage: coverages[vaccineIdx*numYears + yearIdx]
           }

            // save on db
            const queryInsert = {
                text: 'INSERT INTO coverages (vaccine, country, region, year, value) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5);',
                values: [vaccines[vaccineIdx], country, '', years[yearIdx], coverages[vaccineIdx*numYears + yearIdx]]
            }
            var printText = '[INSERT ' + country + ' IN coverages]';
            var queryRes = await postgreSQLlib.query(queryInsert, printText);
        }
    }
}
```

**scraperCovIt.js**:

```
var textract = require('textract');
var postgreSQLlib = require('../middlewares/postgreSQLlib.js');

var methods = {};
var jsons = [];
var mainUrl = 'http://www.salute.gov.it/portale/documentazione/p6_2_8_3_1.jsp?id=20';
var urls = [ 
    {year: '2013', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_0_fileAllegati_itemFile_1_file.pdf'}, 
    {year: '2012', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_5_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {year: '2011', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_6_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}
];

methods.download = async function(req, res) {
    await extractText();
}

async function extractText() {
    var config = {
        preserveLineBreaks: true
    };
    urls.forEach(function(url) {
        textract.fromUrl(url.link, config, async function(error, text) {
            if(error) {
                throw error;
            }
            switch(url.year) {
                case '2011': 
                case '2012':
                    await extractTextType1(url, text);
                    break;
                case '2013': 
                    await extractTextType2(url, text);
                    break;
                default:
                    await console.log('Error: no case');
            }
        });
    });
}

async function extractTextType1(url, text) {
    var matrix = [];
    var map = [];
    var vaccines = [];
    var regionsTemp = [];
    var regions = [];
    var regionLength = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

    var textArray = text.split('\n');
    for(var i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
        matrix[i] = textArray[i].split(' ');
    }

    matrix[0].shift();
    vaccines = matrix[0];
    map[0] = vaccines;

    for(var i = 0; i < regionLength.length; i++) {
        var j = i + 1; 
        var indexToRemove = 0;
        var numberToRemove = regionLength[i];
        var region = matrix[j].splice(indexToRemove, numberToRemove);
        regionsTemp.push(region);
        map[j+1] = matrix[j];
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < regionsTemp.length; i++) {
        var region = '';
        if(regionLength[i] > 1) {
            region = regionsTemp[i].join(' ');
        }
        else {
            region = regionsTemp[i].join('');
        }
        regions.push(region);
    }
    map[1] = regions;

    for(var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            map[i][j] = map[i][j].replace(/\r/g, '');
        }
    }

    vaccines = map.shift();
    regions = map.shift();

    var thisJson = map.reduce(function(result, v, i) {
        v.forEach(async function(o, k) {
            var obj = createJsonObjectCoverage(url.year, 'Italy', vaccines[k], regions[i], o);
            // save on db
            const queryInsertDoNothing = {
                text: 'INSERT INTO coverages (vaccine, country, region, year, value) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) ON CONFLICT (vaccine, country, region, year, value) DO NOTHING;',
                values: [vaccines[k], 'Italy', regions[i], url.year, o]
            };
            var printText = '[INSERT Italy IN coverages]';
            var queryRes = await postgreSQLlib.query(queryInsertDoNothing, printText);
        });
        return result;
    }, jsons);
}

async function extractTextType2(url, text) {
    // similar code to extractTextType1(url, text)
}

function createJsonObjectCoverage(year, country, vaccine, region, coverage) {
    return {
        year: year, 
        country: country, 
        region: region, 
        vaccine: vaccine, 
        coverage: coverage
    };
}

module.exports = methods;
```

The problem is that the inserts in the database do not work as they should.

The result of running **app.js** with **scraperCov.js** is:

```
START

Connected to db at localhost:5432 as admin (pass: admin)
[CREATE TABLE coverages] OK query

COUNTRY: Albania

COUNTRY: Austria
[INSERT Albania IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query

COUNTRY: Belgium
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Austria IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] OK query

Connection has ended

FINISH
[INSERT Belgium IN coverages] ERR query
```

As you can see from the prints, at the end there is an error because the connection is closed before the insertions end.
In addition, the insertions are not in order (under the word `COUNTRY: Albania`, there is nothing, while under the word `COUNTRY: Austria` there is the result of some queries related to Albania, etc.).

The result of running **app.js** with **scraperCovIt.js** is instead:

```
START

Connected to db at localhost:5432 as admin (pass: admin)
[CREATE TABLE coverages] OK query

Connection has ended

FINISH
```

In this case, the inserts are not exactly executed.

How can I solve?

These are days that I try to solve this problem but I don't know how to do it. It's the first time I use `async/await` and I'm having a lot of trouble.

Thanks to anyone who wants to help me

Comment: You don't `await` on `insert(res)`

Comment: You seem to be a little confused about what `await` does.  Statements like `await console.log(...)` do absolutely nothing different than just `console.log(...)`.  `await` does something useful with it awaits a promise that is tied to an asynchronous operation.  My guess is you're using `await` on one or more functions that don't return a promise and expecting it to actually await completion of the asynchronous, but it won't do that unless the function returns a promise that is tied to the async operation.

Comment: In addition, `return await fn()` is no different than `return fn()`.  If `fn()` returns a promise, then you can just directly return that promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 You're probabbly right. Could you help me fix the code?

Comment: I don't know the libraries you're using (specifically the database), but you should visit every single use of `await` and ensure that the thing you're awaiting is a promise.  If not, you either need to change the function you're calling to return a promise or you will need a different design than using `await`.

Comment: Here's one that's clearly wrong: `await extractText();`.  If you look at `extractText()`, it does return a promise (only because it's declared `async`), but that promise is not connected at all to the asynchronous operations inside the function.  That whole `extractText()` function has to be redesigned to communicate back via a promise when it's actually done.  You can't successfully mix callbacks and promises which is what `extractText()` is doing in its implementation.

Comment: @jfriend00 So, the problem in **scraperCovIt.js** is in `v.forEach(async function(o, k) {` because I'm calling a callback function as `async`? While in **scraperCov.js** I have `dowload` that is `async` but doesn't return any promises, right? Then there is `await request` that it should return a promise but in reality it does not, right? I'm a bit confuse

Comment: Yep, those are all problems.  You also can't use `await` to pause a `.forEach()` loop.  It doesn't work that way.  Honestly, there are so many problems in this code that it's a bit daunting to even try to write an answer.  I'd be willing to show you how one section of code could be rewritten in an answer if that would help.

Comment: @jfriend00 Anything can help me, it helps me. Unfortunately, it's the first time I've been programming in Node.js and I'm not used to asynchronous programming.
But I have to do this work in Node so if you could help me, I would be very happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we've discussed in comments, there's a lot wrong here.  Here's a partial list of concepts:

1. `await` only waits for an async operation if you await a promise that is directly tied to the completion of your async operation.  Using `await` on anything other than a promise doesn't do anything useful.  It has no magic powers to know when some underlying asynchronous operation is done.  `await` only follows a promise.
2. `await` inside a `.forEach()` loop doesn't pause execution of that loop.
3. Don't mix callback code and promise code.  It's really, really hard to make things work properly when mixing them.  If you have some code that only takes a callback, then convert it to a new function that returns a promise.  You can often use `util.promisify()` to create that new function in one line of code.
4. I can't possibly attack your whole code as I don't even know what all of it is doing, but I will pick out a few examples and show you how to fix them.  I started looking at `extractText()` which returns a promise (only because it's declared `async`, but that promise isn't connected at all to the asynchronous operations inside it.
5. That led me to some of the functions that `extractText()` calls such as `extractTextType1()` so I'll show you how to fix that first.

In `extractTextType1()`, you are using `await postgreSQLlib.query(...)` inside a `.forEach()` loop which is inside a `.reduce()` loop.  `await` doesn't cause either of those types of loops to pause at all.  As such your `extractTextType1()` function will return long before any of those queries are done.  Since it looks like these queries (which are actually inserts) don't have to be sequenced and can run in parallel, we can simply collect the promises from all the queries into an array and then use `Promise.all()` to track when they are all done.

That code looks like this:

```
function extractTextType1(url, text) {
    var matrix = [];
    var map = [];
    var vaccines = [];
    var regionsTemp = [];
    var regions = [];
    var regionLength = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

    var textArray = text.split('\n');
    for(var i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
        matrix[i] = textArray[i].split(' ');
    }

    matrix[0].shift();
    vaccines = matrix[0];
    map[0] = vaccines;

    for(var i = 0; i < regionLength.length; i++) {
        var j = i + 1; 
        var indexToRemove = 0;
        var numberToRemove = regionLength[i];
        var region = matrix[j].splice(indexToRemove, numberToRemove);
        regionsTemp.push(region);
        map[j+1] = matrix[j];
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < regionsTemp.length; i++) {
        var region = '';
        if(regionLength[i] > 1) {
            region = regionsTemp[i].join(' ');
        }
        else {
            region = regionsTemp[i].join('');
        }
        regions.push(region);
    }
    map[1] = regions;

    for(var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            map[i][j] = map[i][j].replace(/\r/g, '');
        }
    }

    vaccines = map.shift();
    regions = map.shift();

    let promises = [];
    var thisJson = map.reduce(function(result, v, i) {
        v.forEach(async function(o, k) {
            var obj = createJsonObjectCoverage(url.year, 'Italy', vaccines[k], regions[i], o);
            // save on db
            const queryInsertDoNothing = {
                text: 'INSERT INTO coverages (vaccine, country, region, year, value) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) ON CONFLICT (vaccine, country, region, year, value) DO NOTHING;',
                values: [vaccines[k], 'Italy', regions[i], url.year, o]
            };
            var printText = '[INSERT Italy IN coverages]';
            promises.push(postgreSQLlib.query(queryInsertDoNothing, printText));
        });
        return result;
    }, jsons);
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Now `extraTextType1()` returns a promise that resolves only when ALL the asynchronous operations inside are done.  If any of them fail, it will reject.

Also, note that `extraTextType1()` is no longer declared `async` because there's no use of `await`.  It just returns a promise directly.  If you needed to sequence these inserts, then the looping would need a more thorough rewrite to do them one at a time.

---

Assuming you apply similar fixes to `extraTextType2()`, now lets fix the containing function `extractText()`.  Here, we promisify `textract.fromUrl()` so we aren't trying to mix callbacks and promises and we change the `.forEach()` loop to a `for/of` loop so that `await` will work with the loop.  Then, remove `await` from the `console.log()`:

```
const util = require('util');
const textractFromUrl = util.promisify(textract.fromUrl);

async function extractText() {
    var config = {
        preserveLineBreaks: true
    };
    for (let url of urls) {
        let text = await textractFromUrl(url.link, config);
        switch(url.year) {
            case '2011': 
            case '2012':
                await extractTextType1(url, text);
                break;
            case '2013': 
                await extractTextType2(url, text);
                break;
            default:
                console.log('Error: no case');
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can cleanup the download function by changing from this:

```
methods.download = async function(req, res) {
    await extractText();
}
```

to this:

```
methods.download = function(req, res) {
    return extractText();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I've tested the code, it works perfectly. Now I try to understand it and then I try to solve the other file. Do you have any guide/tutorial to advise me to better understand `async/await`?

Comment: @ComeDown - The usual mistake with `async/await` is trying to use it before you understand asynchronous programming and promises.  Those are pre-requisites.  `Async/await` do not replace that understanding.  They make programming easier in some circumstances, but one still must fully understand asynchronous programming and how promises are used for asynchronous programming. Then, and only then, can you take advantage of simplifying some code by using `async/await`. Trying to use `async/await` instead of understanding asynchronous programming and promises will get you in trouble.

Comment: Thank you. Today I solved the problems of **scraperCov.js** too. I learned a lot. Thank you!